# Extract IDs from polygons intersecting with other polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, modelbuilder

I'm currently building a model where I have to extract all IDs from the red outline polygons containing the green polygon.

[image: red and green polygons example]

In the provided example I would like the green highlighted polygon to get a row containing the 2 IDs of the red outline polygons.

Comment: I would recommend using the intersect tool -> https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/intersect.htm. The resulting layer will have combined values of both layers, so then you can append the values to your green polygons.